# How to compile a function for multiple values of a parameter known in compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time, compile-time-constant

I'm writing a C++ function that at the moment receives a parameter via template. The function is complicated, but to simplify the question, consider a function like this:

```
template <int a> int foo(int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

But in the final program, `a` in above function will be known at runtime (not compile time) however the user is forced to provide `a` in the range of 1 to 5. In other words, I may not know `a` exactly in compile time but I'm sure that `a` would be one of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.
How can I compile above function 5 times each for a different `a` and at runtime choose to run the proper one?
One solution is to define different versions of `foo` like `foo_1`, `foo_2`, ... compiled for different `a`s but it obviously increases the amount of copied code especially when the function is big. Is there any better solution?

**EDIT**
My goal is to **avoid** something like below and have a `switch` in runtime deciding which one to use.

```
int foo_1(int b){
    return 1+b;
}
int foo_2(int b){
    return 2+b;
}
int foo_3(int b){
    return 3+b;
}
int foo_4(int b){
    return 4+b;
}
int foo_5(int b){
    return 5+b;
}
```

Comment: If it's known at runtime, you can't have it as a template parameter.

Comment: I know. What I'm trying to say is that I cannot use `template` but I want to use something similar to reduce the amount of copied code, with the pre-known information that `a` would be in the range `[1,5]`.

Comment: You have two choices to deal with the `a`. 1. Check the value of `a` before calling `foo`. 2. Throw an exception from `foo` is `a` is not within the expected range.

Comment: You can specialize it for the values you need and use typedef's

Comment: To achieve what you want at runtime you could think of a solution like `std::map<int,void (*)(int)>` (i.e. using function pointers or functor objects).

Comment: @Farzad: I still don't understand why you cannot just make `a` a regular (non-template) parameter.

Comment: @ChristianHackl I want to have different compiled versions of a function. The reason behind it relates to my code. I'm going to probably use my function for a CUDA program and knowing a variable at compile time reduces the condition checks, and may free up some registers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this comes to mind:

```
template <int a> int foo_impl(int b){
    return a+b;
}

int (*foos[5])(int) = {
   foo_impl<1>,
   foo_impl<2>,
   foo_impl<3>,
   foo_impl<4>,
   foo_impl<5>
};

int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return (foos[a-1])(b);
}
```

I hope there's are real benefit in your real code for this :)